# Background image does not look fit in Simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, background, viewcontroller

I'm new to Xcode and programming in swift. I downloaded an image from Google, added it to the assets, created an image view (disabled size classes), and set it as background image on view controller. However, when I run the app, the image is not fit to the screen in Simulator and I see white parts. I don't know how to fix it. 
P.S. I am using Xcode 7.2 and I am NOT supposed to fix this problem programmingly.

This is how it appears when I try to add autoLayout to it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXY5q.jpg)

Comment: You need to add constraints to the image view so that it always stretches to the borders of the view controller. Look into a tutorial or some documentation to learn the basics of iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you apply autoLayout to it?
In your Main Storyboard, open view Hierarchy. 
Control drag from your Image View to View, and select 
Leading space from container, trailing space from container, vertical space from top layout guide and vertical spacing from bottom layout guide.

[image]

Comment: I tried to do autoLayout but it does not work. I took a screen shot. Click on the link in my question to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with this setting:

[image: Picture Mode]